# GCC ignores calling convention attribute

Tags: gcc, c++11, g++, calling-convention, stdcall

does anyone know why this doesnt work?

```
void test() [[stdcall]] {
        std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}
```

when I try to compile with C++11 dialect it says:

"warning: 'stdcall' attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]"

Why is that? I have a function that really needs to have the stdcall calling convention. The default calling convention in GCC is cdecl. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work:

```
#include <iostream>
[[gnu::stdcall]]
void test()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}
```

or you can use the old syntax `__attribute__((stdcall))`. Compiling with `g++ -std=c++11 -m32` I get no warning.